# Angular2 Failing to update to RC7 - zone.js & reflect-metadata

Tags: javascript, angular, zonejs, reflect-metadata

I'm trying to get my application to run with the new RC7 of angular but i cant seem to be able to get it done, as the console shouts:

```
Promise rejection: Zone.assertZonePatched is not a function      angular2-polyfills.js:489
```

And when this ***somehow*** disappears, this pops up:

```
Reflect.getMetadata is not a function (..)                                core.umd.js:472
```

Looks like the implementation changed, and mine isn't updated although i `npm install`ed everything from scratch, update my `package.json` as follows:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.21",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.19",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17",
    "angular2-apollo": "^0.4.6",
    "apollo-client": "^0.4.13",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2"
  }
}
```

index.html: (I have also tried refering to [unpkg.com](https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.8/Reflect.js) for the packages, no success)

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>My App</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MIwDKRSSImVFAZCVLtU0LMDdON6KVCrZHyVQQj6e8wIEJkW4tvwqXrbMIya1vriY" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/javascript/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ux8v3A6CPtOTqOzMKiuo3d/DomGaaClxFYdCu2HPMBEkf6x2xiDyJ7gkXU0MWwaD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Your `package.json` belongs to `Angular2.0` version.

Comment: @micronyks what do you mean?

Comment: You are installing Angular2.0(recent release packages) If you are looking for RC7 package, kindly refer to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39496055/which-angular-forms-version-for-angular-2-rc7/39496132#39496132 where I have shown RC7 packages with systemjs not webpack.

Comment: @micronyks Hey, updated my package.json, this still produces the same error, any ideas?

Comment: @micronyks SOLVED, see the answer below

Comment: what about RC7? does't it solve your problem for RC7 too?

Comment: @micronyks Yes, i have updated my package.json to `"@angular/XXX": "2.0.0-rc.7"` and did as the below answer suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTEs**:

- As per package.json, you are using ***Angular2.0.0*** You don't need ***angular2-polyfills.js***
- Remove ***"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17"***, from ***package.json***
- Remove ***angular2-polyfills.js*** from ***index.html***

  ```
  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
  ```

Infact, if you have **angular2** folder under **node_modules** then delete that folder. latest angular2 packages will be available in **@angular** folder under **node_modules**.

Comment: You're basically saying i should remove the dependency of angular2 from my `package.json` and just re-`npm i`? (updated my `package.json` dependencies to those with -rc.7)

Comment: And the angular2 package doesn't seem to exist inside @angular under node_modules :|

Comment: Clean node_modules folder and then run `npm install` it will give you packages inside @angular under node_modules.

Comment: Once you got latest packages, remove `angular2-polyfills.js` from `index.html` and then run application.

Comment: Should i keep the `angular2` dependency in the package.json or not?

Comment: Remove `"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17",` from package.json

Comment: THANK YOU! that worked!!, please note in your answer to remove this dependency from my package.json and ill accept and upvote it for the future readers ! :)

Comment: @sanket This doesn't work for me. I'm already using angular 2.0.0 and I don't use any polyfills.js in my package.json nor index.html.  So I'm not sure why I'm still getting "Reflect.getMetadata is not a function" error.

Comment: @Sam can you please create new post with your details